# Present UIView over darkened UIWindow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwindow

I am trying to present a UIView while at the same time darkening the rest of the screen. However, I am having difficulty. This is my code:

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

self.viewToDarken = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
[self.viewToDarken setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.viewToDarken setAlpha:0.0f];
[window insertSubview:self.viewToDarken aboveSubview:self.hostView];

[self.hostView addSubview:self];


[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                 animations:^(void) {
                     [self setFrame:[self destinationFrame]];
                     if (self.viewToDarken) self.viewToDarken.alpha = 0.7f;
                 }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [self notifyDidShow];
                 }];
```

However, I can't get the view to darken to get placed below the view I am adding (self). any ideas why this doesn't work?

Thanks!

Comment: would it be self.view instead of self ? can you try..

Comment: no this isn't a view controller its a view

Comment: Then I think it should be [self addSubview:self.hostView];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the `viewToDarken` above `self.hostView` then adding `self` to `hostView` so of course self will be below `viewToDarken`. You need to add `viewToDarken` below `self.hostView`.

What you have now is:

hostView + self(view) (below) -> viewToDarken

You need

viewToDarken (below)-> hostView + self(view)

You should have:

```
[window insertSubview:self.viewToDarken belowSubview:self.hostView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 views here; `self`, `hostView` and `viewToDarken`. You are inserting the `viewToDarken` above `hostView`, and then you are adding `self` to the hostView. Because `self` is a subview of `hostView`, it will be below any views that `hostView` is below.

You probably instead want to add the `viewToDarken` to `hostView`. Or you could insert it behind the `hostView` like so:

```
[self.hostView.superview insertSubview:self.viewToDarken belowSubview:self.hostView];
```

Whichever way you do it, you are going to need to take into account coordinate systems. Make sure to check out `-[UIView convertRect:fromView:]`.

Also, instead of using absolute "magic" numbers for the frame, use window.bounds:

```
self.viewToDarken = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:window.bounds];
```